# Move cell with sum function down as new entries occur using row.count

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a bit surprised this has proven to be such a challenge. On `sheet 1` I have the input which looks as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

erw = Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
'erw.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDow

If Len(Range("c3")) <> 0 Then

Sheet2.Cells(erw, 1) = Range("c3")
Sheet2.Cells(erw, 2) = Range("c4")
Sheet2.Cells(erw, 3) = Range("c5")

Range("c3") = ""
Range("c4") = ""
Range("c5") = ""

Else
    MsgBox "You must enter an amount"
End If

End Sub
```

No issues with the above, where I'm running into a problems is with the following on sheet 2 where the information is stored:

```
Sub AddUp()

Dim rngcount As Long
Dim TotalA As Long
Dim rng2 As Range

rngcount = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng2 = Range("A28")

TotalA = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("a1:a" & rngcount))

rng2 = TotalA
```

The real issue is the following `Set rng2 = Range("A28")` as this is essentially a cheat I've been using. I know that there will not be more than 26 entries to be summed and then a new sheet will be started. I currently have the `TotalA` amount `Set` to be put in `A28`, but what I am trying to do is have the `TotalA` cell move down as more entries are put in. Put another way I would rather the range where `TotalA` will be able to move as more entries are put in.

I began with the following `erw.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDow`but I moved away from that as the insertion of a row needs to occur on `sheet2`I've left it here for this posting in case there is any valuable feed back.

What I've been focusing on instead is trying to use `CurrentRegion.offset(1)` to keep moving the cell that holds the sum function down. Problem is I cannot figure out how to declare a range based on `rngcount` This may be the problem because perhaps I should not be using `rngcount` as it is not an `object`, but my thinking is/was that I could turn that `rngcount` into an object and then use `CurrentRegion.offset(1)` A bit long winded, hope the goal comes through clearly. Thanks

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this and see if it does what you want.

```
Sub AddUp()

Dim rngcount As Long
Dim TotalA As Long
Dim rng2 As Range

rngcount = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng2 = Cells(rngcount + 1, 1)

TotalA = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("a1:a" & rngcount))

rng2 = TotalA

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually like to put total formulas in the worksheet instead of doing the math in the macro.

```
Sub AddUp()

Dim rngcount As Long
Dim TotalA As Long
Dim TotalStartRng As Range
Dim TotalEndRng As Range

rngcount = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set TotalStartRng = Cells(1, 1)
Set TotalEndRng = Cells(rngcount, 1)

Cells(rngcount + 1, 1) = "=SUM(" & TotalStartRng.Address & ":" & TotalEndRng.Address & ")"

End Sub
```